# ga.getAll() breaks a function making it return undefined in a javascript GTM variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

So, I created "javascript code" variable in GTM and trying to get `clientID` via `ga.getAll`, and have the following code:

```
function foo() {
  var trackers = ga.getAll();
  if (trackers.length > 0) {
    return  trackers[0].get('trackingId') === 'UA-188398635-1' ? trackers[0].get('clientId') : 'nonon';
  }
}
```

But it always returns `undefined`, even if I make it return a string constant `'asdasd'` - having `ga.getAll` in the code is enough for the `function` to  break. And the most confusing thing - the same code works in debug console just fine. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Since `foo` returns undefined, that means that `trackers.length` is 0. Try this:

```
function foo() {
    var trackers = ga.getAll();
    if(trackers.length >0) {
        return  trackers[0].get('trackingId') === 'UA-188082465-1' ? trackers[0].get('clientId') : 'nonon';
    } else {
        return 'This is not undefined';
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, still returns "undefined"

Comment: @Herman what is the value of `trackers[0].get('clientId')`?

Comment: I can't get it as the function breaks as soon as I call ga.getall

Comment: @Herman what is the error that you get?

Comment: There is no error in the log, the function just returns "undefined"

Comment: @Herman then how do you know that the function breaks when you call `ga.getall`?

Comment: There is a variable where the output from the function should be, it has the value "undefined"

Comment: @Herman that means that the function returned undefined, not that the function crashed. If you mean that `trackers` is undefined after `var trackers = ga.getAll();`, then the function was executed and returned undefined.